# How to authenticate Titanium client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication, devise, titanium

I've got a Rails app with the devise gem for user authentication.

What is the best way to authenticate an user on a Titanium app? I would like the user enters his credentials on the Titanium app and then that the rails app checks the login/password with devise.

Communication between apps is done through a REST interface and I use custom HTTP headers to transfer credentials.

Comment: you need to provide information on the custom http headers.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a view laid out like this, that accepts a username and password:

```
<Alloy>
    <View layout="vertical" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="80%" top="25%">
        <TextField id="username" height="40dp" width="60%"/>
        <TextField id="pwd" height="40dp" width="60%"/>
        <Button id="loginBtn" width="80%"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Once a user enters input and hits the login button you send an http request. Here is a nice [guide on the ins and outs,](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle) but it functions similar to most [HTTPClient wrappers.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    timeout : 2000,
    onload : function() {
        // Successful return, do something with it
        var retval = this.responseText;
    },
    onerror : function() {
        Ti.API.error(this.responseText);
    }

});
xhr.open('POST',"http://your-web-service");

// Set headers here, _after_ opening 
var userinfo = {username : $.username.value, pwd : $.pwd.value};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization_Custom_Header", "Assemble your header here or use OAuth");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: this can work but it is not passing the credentials in the header which is what he stated in the original question

Comment: missed that part, updated my answer reflect the info he gave.